# Wait for RxJS data, and how to return?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a function that creates a user, but before that user is created I want to check if another user with the same userName already exists in that session:

```js
public createUser(form: FormGroup, sessionCode?: string): void {
  if (sessionCode && this.checkForDuplicateUserInSession(form, sessionCode)) return;

  this.apollo.mutate<CreateUser>({
    mutation: CREATE_USER,
    variables: {
      name: form.controls['user'].get('userName')?.value,
    },
  }).subscribe(
    ...
  );
}

private checkForDuplicateUserInSession(form: FormGroup, sessionCode?: string): void {
  this.apollo.query<GetSession>({
    query: GET_SESSION,
    variables: {
      code: sessionCode
    }
  }).subscribe({
    next: ({data}) => {
      return data.getSession.players.some((player) => player.name === form.controls['user'].get('userName')?.value);
    }
  });
}
```

The `checkForDuplicateUserInSession()` does correctly check if another user already exists or not, but I'm not sure how I can use that in the `createUser()` function.

Do I have to make a make a `userIsDuplicate$` observable to which I push the `some()` result and then subscribe to that? Or is there a different way I'm not seeing?

Comment: Why doesn't `checkForDuplicateUserInSession` return `Observable<boolean>`? (Right now it doesn't actually return `boolean`, even, just `undefined`; I'm surprised TS isn't telling you that.)

Comment: I've editted the code in the question, my bad.

Comment: Same question, though: why doesn't it return an observable, so the value can actually be used by the caller? Returning from the subscription callback doesn't do anything, as the void return type should make clear - you're asking https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3001761, basically.

Comment: You cannot return the value inside the subscribe to the function. That's the point of the question.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you can. I know you can't. The correct types tell you you can't. I'm suggesting you _return an `Observable<boolean>`_. Have a look at e.g. https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt6 which introduces using observables in Angular.

Comment: Oh or https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt4#observable-data

Comment: `this.apollo.query` doesn't return an Observable, but an Subscription. So how do I return an Observable?

Comment: You sure? If so calling `.subscribe` on it would be a problem, because a `Subscription` [doesn't have that](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subscription).

Comment: Because I subscribed to it it was a subscription. Without the subscribe it's an Observable. Thank you, issue is resolved now. I'll post the answer later.

Comment: It _always_ returns an Observable, which has a [subscribe method](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Observable#subscribe) that returns a Subscription. But yes, it's the subscribing that makes the overall result of the expression a Subscription.

Answer (score -1):

Use `lastValueFrom` function inside method `checkForDuplicateUserInSession` to transform Observable in Promise ([doc here](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom)). After taht uses async/await on
`createUser` method.

Example:

```
public async createUser(form: FormGroup, sessionCode?: string): void {
    if (sessionCode && await this.checkForDuplicateUserInSession(form, sessionCode)) return;
    
    this.apollo.mutate<CreateUser>({
        mutation: CREATE_USER,
        variables: {
            name: form.controls['user'].get('userName')?.value,
        },
    }).subscribe(
          ...
    );
}
    
private checkForDuplicateUserInSession(form: FormGroup, sessionCode?: string): void {
    return lastValueFrom(this.apollo.query<GetSession>({
        query: GET_SESSION,
        variables: {
            code: sessionCode
        }
    }).subscribe({
        next: ({data}) => {
            return data.getSession.players.some((player) => player.name === form.controls['user'].get('userName')?.value);
        }
    }));
}
```